# SecretKey destroy in JAVA (android)

Tags: java, android, key

Hi I have a `SecretKey` which I use for encrypting data in sqlite db.
What is best practise for `SecretKey`:

1. keep key on memory
2. destroy key after usage and request `SecretKey` every time from storage when required.